# React Navigation v 2 and Redux

Tags: react-native

I have been using react-native-router-flux in my app and configured the store and it works like a charm.

I am now planning to use react-navigation v2.8 in my app and i am struggling to  complete the configureStore.

I supposed that the configureStore would be used as is from the react-native-router-flux example. Below is the sample code from my working react-native-router-flux sample.

```
/* global __DEV__ */
import { Router } from 'react-native-router-flux'; //this is not to be used 
in react-navigation
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger';
import reducers from './index';

connect()(Router); //ROuter is not avaible in react-navigation
let middleware;

if (__DEV__) {
  const logger = createLogger();
  middleware = [thunk, ReduxPromise, logger];
  //middleware = [thunk, ReduxPromise];
} else {
  middleware = [thunk, ReduxPromise];
}

export function configureStore() {
  const store = compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))(
    createStore
  )(reducers);

  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { persistor, store };
}

export const { persistor, store } = configureStore();
```

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation can be used as a general JSX Component that can be enclosed within the `Provider` and thus the whole UI tree will have the store available inside the `context`. So you can just initialize the store in your app's root, keep it as a state variable inside
it and pass it to the context using `Provider`.

Code for configuring your store and making it available down in your UI tree made using React Navigation should look like below:

**Your Root component should look like this**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import AppStack from './app/AppNavigation';
import getStore from './app/store';

export default class App extends Component {
   constructor (props) {
   super(props);
      this.state = {
         store : getStore()
      }
   }


   render() {
      return (
         <Provider store={this.state.store} >
            <AppStack /> . // This is your React Navigation Stack.
         </Provider>
      );
   }
}
```

**and your `getStore` should look like this:**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';

export default function getStore () {
     const enhancer = compose(
              applyMiddleware(
                //your middlewares here..
              )
     );
     const store = createStore(reducers);
     return store;
}
```

**and the AppStack can look like this:**

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import FirstScreen from './components/FirstScreen';

export default AppStack = createStackNavigator({
    Screen1: {
        screen: FirstScreen,
        //other routes.... 
    },
});
```

This is just a mere simplest possible example.